# Class redefinition error in C++ while deriving an Abstract Class from another Abstract Class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I'm new to C++ abstract classes and I'm trying to learn how to work with it. So I started by defining an abstract class with only pure functions, let's call this class `SceneObj`, so far so good. Afterwards, I start by defining a new abstract class that I'm calling `IScreen`; this new `Class` is, also, another abstract class, but it add new requirements.

Unfortunately when trying to compile this simple code I ran into the following error: `error C2011: 'IScreen' : 'class' type redefinition`.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and the code that I'm trying to compile is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class SceneObj
{
protected:
    float center;

public:
    virtual void SetCenter(float,float,float) = 0;
    virtual void SetCenter(float) = 0;
    virtual float GetCenter() = 0;
    virtual ~SceneObj();
};

class IScreen : public SceneObj
{
public:
    virtual void SetCenter(float,float,float) = 0;
    virtual void SetCenter(float) = 0;
    virtual float GetCenter() = 0;
    virtual float GetStartCorner() = 0;

    virtual void SetSize(float,float) = 0;
    virtual void SetSize(long) = 0;
    virtual long GetSize() = 0;

    virtual ~IScreen();
};
```

Could someone point me what/where is the flaw in this code?

edit: Changed code to a minimal one
edit2: This is in a `header file` and apparently if i change it to a `.cpp` it compiles without problems. But I needed/wanted to declare my class in `headers` and then define then in `.cpp`.

Comment: Does the compiler add anything like "previously declared at" info?

Comment: Since one class is inheriting from the other, it's not necessary to declare the same functions with the same signatures again.  Try removing those.

Comment: Trying a minimal, self-contained example without dependencies like Eigen would help much. I can't test and by just looking, I don't see any reason for your error.

Comment: @iavr I just changed the example, the error persist

Comment: @yamilife  Instead of changing your example simply show all messages of the compiler.

Comment: @yamilife  As I already wrote in my post your example is irrelevant to the problem. The class is defined somewhere else and compiler messages should point the duplicate definition.

Comment: Where is this code located, header or cpp file?

Comment: @yamilife This example is much better but if this is a header file that you include in a cpp along with other stuff, then still the error (redefinition) may be elsewhere. So the example is still not self-contained.

Comment: @iavr well, i included it in a cpp with only a include to the header

Comment: @@yamilife One more. See my updated post.

Comment: You need to explain the file structure you're using. What cpp files, what headers, what files include what other files, etc. The problem sounds like it has nothing to do with your specific code and instead depends on how you're misusing the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

C++programs also use the preprocessor to define header guards. Header guards
rely on preprocessor variables. Preprocessor variables have one of two
possible states: defined or not defined. The `#define` directive takes a name and defines
that name as a preprocessor variable. There are two other directives that test whether
a given preprocessor variable has or has not been defined: `#ifdef` is true if the variable
has been defined, and `#ifndef` is true if the variable has not been defined. If the test is
true, then everything following the `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`is processed up to the
matching `#endif`.
We can use these facilities to guard against multiple inclusion as follows:

```
 #ifndef SALES_DATA_H
 #define SALES_DATA_H
 #include <string>
 struct Sales_data {
 std::string bookNo;
 unsigned units_sold = 0;
 double revenue = 0.0;
 };
 #endif  //SALES_DATA_H
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, in the header file you will find something LIKE the follwing:

```
#ifndef __*__SceneObj
#define __*__SceneObj__
//Place the abstract class here
#endif
```

So you have to put the abstract class in between the #define and the #endif. (This is the definition the compiler will consider). you simply don't have these etiquettes  on the cpp file. That is why it works there.
Additionally try to have one class per header file, so do not declare the child class on the same header file.

Answer (score -2):

It means that somewhere you already have defined type IScreen. Usually the compiler gives a reference to the duplicated definition.

So investigate the error message.

As for you code snippet then it is irrelevant.

MS VS usually gives several messages if it found an error.

Another reason can be that you included the cpp module with member function definitions in the module with main.

For example

Header file: header.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class SceneObj
{
   //...
};

class IScreen : public SceneObj
{
   //...
};
```

cpp module with member function definitions: module,cpp

```
#include "header.h"
//...
```

module with main

```
#include "header.h"
#include "module.cpp"
//...
```

Also include directive

```
#pragma once
```

in your header file.

Comment: -1: "Investigate the error message" is hardly a good answer to this question.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit It is a very good answer taking into account the information that is provided.

Comment: Not enough information is a reason to ask for more from OP not to post a bad answer.

Comment: @Borgleader It is a very good answer because the error message contains all required information.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Your answer should be a comment and you know it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Note that I did not downvote you, despite the fact that I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: +1: Given the absence of information in the question, this edited answer is now probably close to the actual problem.

Comment: @iavr  It was initially clear because without any doubts the error message contains a reference to the duplicated definition.